# jquery post not passing all parameters

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have this jquery code:

```
var idd = $(this).attr("id");
var page = $(this).attr("page");

    var data = "lastmsg="+idd+"&page="+page;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_more.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(html){
            $("ol#live_updates").append(html);
            $("#more"+idd).remove(); // removing old more button
        }
    });
```

and this is the "ajax_more.php" code:

```
if(isset($_POST['lastmsg']))
{
    $lastmsg = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastmsg']);
    $page = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['page']);

        echo $lastmsg . " " . $page;
}
```

Only ($lastmsg) passed, but any other parameter like ($page) is not passed. Where is the problem ??
i tried ($.post) and ($.ajax) with "POST" type, both not working...

Comment: Data != Query String. In any case, you can see what *is* passed using a tool like FireBug which will help isolate similar issues in the future.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between [POS and GET](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) Then the right way to use [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) will be clear

Answer (score 3):

`data` should be an object.

```
var data = {lastmsg: idd, page: page};
```

Comment: Do you get any kind of error message? Check /var/log/apache_error_log,  and the firebug console.

Comment: No, i did not get any error message. One variable passed, the others don't.

Comment: What value are you passing to `page`?

Comment: There are two variables: "lastmsg" and "page",
I want to pass them to the server side "ajax_more.php". But one is passed, the other don't. Why ?

Comment: What value are you passing to `page`?

Comment: @undefined I have a feeling that's the case. `echo $lastmsg . " " . $page;` is probably working correctly and is displaying the empty string that was passed in.

Answer (score -2):

You need to properly encode all of your ajaxed parameters using `encodeURI`.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18874511/2788532) for more information. Also, use your browser's console to debug.

Comment: You shouldn't. This answer only affects GET method.

Comment: @JoeFrambach Yes you should, but if you pass an object as the data parameter jQuery will do it for you automatically.